# Linux script to identify security issues & generate report

Tags: linux, security, scripting

I've previously used a great script on a Linux servers to report on all sorts of security issues.

It generates a comprehensive list of potential security flaws on the machine including:

1. out of date software / bugs
2. open ports
3. incorrect privileges

And it summarises everything in a report along with suggested fixes.

Problem is I cann't remember the name of the script or where to find it?

Any clues?!
J

Comment: I'm guessing there is no right answer to this question, so all reasonable answers get up-votes - but I'll hold out from closing the question until I see an answer with the name of the script I used (which I'll recognise once I see it).

Comment: It would help if you tell us the format of the report, text? html? pdf?

Comment: @chmee - as I recall, just text output on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

*chkrootkit* and *rkhunter* are excellent choices, both being just shell scripts.

Then there are other security tools, such as *Nessus* , *Prelude*, *tripwire* and *aide*.

Comment: Just what I was going to suggest - IME both required some knowledge / research to use on a production system due to false positives (particularly with 'hidden processes'). Nikto (http://cirt.net/nikto2) is handy for webservers. And Snort for network IDS

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are talking about [Lynis](http://www.rootkit.nl/projects/lynis.html), which is a security and system auditing tool.
[Tiger](http://www.nongnu.org/tiger/) is a similar tool.

There is also [Bastille Unix](http://bastille-linux.sourceforge.net/) that lets you harden as you analyze.

**EDIT**: If it is none of the above, maybe is one of these other three (less known).

- [YASAT](http://yasat.sourceforge.net/)
- [sectool](https://fedorahosted.org/sectool/)
- [LSAT](http://usat.sourceforge.net/)